# longtable: won't linebreak while underlined or bold + multirow doesn't center vertically next to a figure

Tags: line-breaking, longtable, multirow

I am trying to create a landscaped longtable: there should be 2 rows with one containing a headline and the other an image, while a multirow is vertically centered next to the image and it's headline.

The problem is a missing linebreak, when I am using formats such as \underline or \bold and that the multi row isn't vertically centered

I've been trying some ideas around here, such as including the \hspace{0pt} input or using a minipage, while I have no idea on how to vertically center the multirow next to an image

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt,        
BCOR=1cm,                           
DIV=12,                              
parskip=half,          
numbers=noendperiod
]{scrartcl}

%general stuff
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tgheros}

%table-edits
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltxtable}   
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}    

%others
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow, multicol}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{todonotes}
%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\begin{document}

    \begin{landscape}

        \begin{longtable}[c]{ | M{3cm} | M{3.3cm} |}

            \caption{mycaption}
            \label{tab:mylabel} \\

                \hline
                \textbf{Headline 1} & \textbf{Headline 2} \tabularnewline
                \hline
                \endhead
                %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

                \multirow{2}{*}{\hspace{0pt} \textbf{ \hspace{0pt} Extremely long text}}  & \hspace{0pt} \underline{ \hspace{0pt} another long cell input} \tabularnewline

                & \missingfigure[figwidth=3cm]{Testing a long text string} \tabularnewline
                \hline

        \end{longtable}

    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is never a line break in a \multirow with `*` and in `\underline`. Regarding centering with \multirow: Read the documentation to understand the problems if large cells are involved.

Comment: but setting * to the 3cm in my case, the first line will be horizontically centered, while the next line is leftsided. how to avoid it? (changing the column type won't work)

Answer (score 0):

Such as @Ulrike Fischer said: line-breaking `\underline` won't work. Therefore the `soul` package brings the command `\ul`.
Though it didn't work for me, I've used the following workaround:
an `\underline` for each line I needed and started playing with the parameters of `\multirow` (replacing * with any length in cm and changing the  from 2 to a certain value until it looked viable for me.

Comment: For multirow use in a fixed width column, you now can replace `{*}` with `{=}`.